# How to extract string between to patterns with special characters in R

Tags: r, regex, gsub

From string `a` I would like to extract everything between `|Request|` and the next occurance of `|`:

```
 a <- "|Request|\nSample inlet port of the HIP cartridge with |overflow| formed "
    
 gsub(".*\\|Request\\| (.+) |.*", "\\1", a)
```

Applying gsub this way did not yield the expected result. How could I do it instead?

Comment: You can get the values using a capturing group `\|Request\|([^|]+)` https://regex101.com/r/zmUIM0/1/

Comment: `stringr::str_match(a, "\\|Request\\|([^|]+)")[,2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use lazy dot, and also your input pattern should match the entire input, given that you are replacing with capture group:

```
a <- "|Request|\nSample inlet port of the HIP cartridge with |overflow| formed "
sub("^.*\\|Request\\|\\s*(.+?)\\s*\\|.*$", "\\1", a)

[1] "Sample inlet port of the HIP cartridge with"
```

Comment: If the |-symbol does not occurr afterwards anymore I would like to get the substring from the first match until the end. How could I do this?

Comment: I don't have enough sample inputs to come up with a good enough alternative regex even worthy of a comment here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sub` to capture everything after `|Request|` until the next `|` occurs.

```
sub(".*\\|Request\\|(.*?)\\|.*", "\\1", a)
#[1] "\nSample inlet port of the HIP cartridge with "
```